# React Native reload app or refresh Drawer.Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

very new to React native.... I have app with Drawer.Navigator...

I implemented login/logout with SecureStore where I keep my token... in my app menu is slightly different when user is logged in or not (I am adding some items in menu)...

When I log User I am setting global variable: global.loggedUser to true or otherwise I set it to false... so depending to global variable I render menu.

```
getToken().then((token) => {
    token !== '' && token !== null
        ? (global.loggedUser = true)
        : (global.loggedUser = false);
    //alert(token + 'and value is..' + global.loggedUser);
});
```

Then I have: function that render navigator:

```
function AppStack(props) {
    if (global.loggedUser === true) {
        console.log('MENU - LOGGED IN!!!');
        return (
            <Drawer.Navigator
```

Everything works except... I need to close and re-open app in order to see changes in my menu...

Is there a way to refresh whole app or something like that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi try by activating fast refresh from debug menu https://reactnative.dev/docs/fast-refresh

Comment: I am wondering.. if this works only on  development builds.. is it going to work on uploading an archive to the app store / Test Flight? Thanks

Comment: Only solution I found so far is import { Restart } from 'fiction-expo-restart';... It seams to me a bit insane to restart totally everything when I just want to refresh my navigation... Is anyone had this issue on login/logout please.